# UITableView Sorting as per Date

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, uitableview

I have some images saved in **~Documents** and I'm showing them in a tableView in a custom cell which looks like

[image: my current tableView]

As you can see the cell have an **imageView, imageName Label, Size Label and Date Label** (the date when image file was created). Right now the images are showing in random order. I want to sort them as per date it was created (ascending/descending)

How can I do so?

Comment: sort your array based on date and reload table view.

Comment: Sort by date.  NSDate objects respond to `compare`, or sometimes it's easier to follow by converting the dates to NSTimeIntervals (which are floating point doubles) and comparing those.

Comment: And NSArray and NSMutableArray both have several `sort` methods to choose from.

Comment: And, as others have indicated, you should ALWAYS "back up" your TableView with an NS(Mutable)Array to contain the actual contents, fetching values from that when you need to populate a cell.  It's convenient to make the array entries be NSMutableDictionary instances, so they can contain all the info on a table row in reasonably straight-forward form.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm trying to use paulrehkugler's method but it gives me error. Can you please suggest the reason?

Comment: Well, it depends on the elements you have in the array.  What are the elements of your array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `NSSortDescriptor` on your array using the date property. Something like this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
arrayUsedForTableView = [arrayUsedForTableView sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[dateSortDescriptor]];
```

where `arrayUsedForTableView` is the array you're using as the model for your `UITableViewDataSource`, and `date` is the property name for the `NSDate` property of the object inside that array.

Then call `-reloadData` on your `UITableView`.

#### Edit:

It's necessary to have an `NSObject` subclass that *has* both the image and the date as the `id`s inside the `NSArray`. Something like this in the header file:

```
@interface MyTableViewModelObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic) NSDate *date;

@end
```

This is necessary because the `NSSortDescriptor` is looking for an object that *has* a date, to sort based on the date property, not *just* a date.

Comment: It crashes:
`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0xa1c1290> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key date.'`

Comment: What are the objects stored in your array? Do they have a property called "date"? Is the property "date" a NSDate?

Comment: The objects in the array you are sorting are __NSCFStrings, aka NSStrings, not an object with a date property.

Comment: Yes, it was earlier `NSString` which I changed to NSDate but the same error occurs with `<__NSDate` 
You mentioned to use `NDate` property. Can you please show me an example of it? What I was doing is 
`NSDate *getDate` and then I tried to use the date object like
`getDate.date` . So am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: You need to have an object that has a date. It doesn't make sense to sort just the dates, because then you don't know which images they correspond to. See my edits.

Comment: so I need to add image object and date object to same array? How do I do that so image corresponds to date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to get a sorted array `files` of files, by creation date, from your document directory:

```
NSMutableArray* files = [NSMutableArray new];
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString* docDir =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSArray* content = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:docDir error:NULL];
for (NSString* file in content) {
    NSDictionary* attrs = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:nil];
    NSDate *date = nil;
    if (attrs) {
        date = (NSDate*)[attrs objectForKey: NSFileCreationDate];
    }

    [files addObject:@{@"path": file,@"createdon":(date ? date : [NSNull null])}];
}

[files sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDictionary* fd1 = obj1;
    NSDictionary* fd2 = obj2;
    NSDate* dt1 = fd1[@"createdon"];
    NSDate* dt2 = fd2[@"createdon"];

    if (dt1 > dt2) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if (dt1 < dt2) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

And then its pretty straightforward to use `files` array as the datasource for your UITableView.
Obviously you might need to modify the code to suit your specific requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As the other responders have hinted:

You don't sort a table view. A table view displays the contents of its data source. You almost always use an array to store the data in a table view.

If you want the items in your table view to be sorted, sort the array you use to fill the table view, then call the table view's reloadData method. That tells the table view that the contents of the data source have changed.

I'm partial to the new NSMutableArray sortUsingSelector: family of methods. You can sort a mutable array by providing a block of code that knows how to compare two objects in your array based on your sort criteria. In your case, you might have an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains the image filename, NSDate, and possibly the file size. You'd write an NSComparator block that knew how to compare the two date fields in a pair of objects, and the system does the work to sort the array.

Comment: Why do you implement comparators when you can get built-in comparison from NSSortDescriptor?

Comment: I tend to prefer comparators over sort descriptors because I have more control, and they are likely to be faster. Sort descriptors have to use KVO to fetch the values for keys, and KVO is relatively slow. It's a question of style and personal taste as much as anything. There are at least 4 different ways to sort arrays: sort descriptors, comparators, selectors, and C function pointers. You can also implement your own sort algorithm if you want, which might let you optimize for certain data-sets.